# Efficiently finding the k-loudest neighbors in a geospatial database using KNN search

Tags: database, search, geospatial, knn

It's kind of geospatial query like k-nearest neighbor problem.
I want to search effectively to find the k-loudest neighbors within a database.

Sound level from the point is calculated as below:

```js
const getSoundLevel = (distance, sourceLevel) => sourceLevel - 20 * Math.log10(distance)
```

`sourceLevel` is the loudness of the origin(0m distance). the function above calculate the sound level hearing that point. According to the definition, whispering from 1m away is louder than shouting from 1km away.

I do not consider about sound mixing. All sound calculated independantly.

I've tried this from MongoDB but I have to scan all within estimated range. I want to more effective way. I currently servey vector database like pinecone but I still have no idea.

A small error can be accepted. But I want to avoid full-index search within range(before loudness calculation points).

Thanks.

MongoDB geospatial query can do this but must do full-search within the range.
loudness is depend on the distance between the given location and the origin point.